# Create a class that has objects of another class

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm newbie in PHP OOP. I need to create a class Place that may have objects of the class Token. How to do this correctly?

```
    class Token {

        var $value;

        function setValue($value) {
            $this->value = $value;
        }

        function getValue() {
            return $this->value;
        }

    }

    class Place {

        var $token;

        function addToken($token) {
            $this->token = $token;
        }

        function getToken() {
            return $this->token;
        }
    }

//...
```

Then I need to create objects of above-defined classes and access Token objects from Place objects:

```
$t = new Token();
$t->setValue(5);
$p = new Place();
$p->addToken($t);
echo $p->getToken()->getValue;
```

Comment: Do you want `Place` to have methods that `Token` may not have?

Comment: Didn't what you have do it already?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code.  I'd add a `Token` typehint to the `addToken()` method, though.

Comment: @siidheesh yes,that's correct.

Comment: I think what you have is already quite ok.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: what do you mean by 'add Token typehint'? Well, if this code is correct, then it means that I understand PHP OOP correctly:)

Comment: @Gusgus What drrcknlsn meant is you could change your `addToken()` signature to `addToken(Token $token)` to make sure that only an instance of `Token` is passed as argument.

Comment: @Gusgus: [Typehinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) is basically a way to enforce that what gets passed into the method is what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
echo $p->getToken()->getValue;
```

to

```
echo $p->getToken()->getValue();
```

and that's all.